# ERROR Cannot read property 'name' of undefined using .subscribe

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm just getting this error -

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

all the time!

This is my code from getclients.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';

import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetclientsService {
  getclientList: AngularFireList<any>;
  array= [];

  constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.getclientList=this.firebase.list('clients');
    this.getclientList.snapshotChanges().subscribe(list=>{
    this.array=list.map(item=>{
      return{
        $key: item.key,
        ...item.payload.val()
        };
    });
  });
 }
 getClientName($key){
   if ($key=="0")
     return "";
   else{
     return _.find(this.array, (obj)=>{return obj.$key==$key;})['name'];
    }
 }
```

}

And this is my employeelist.component.ts:

```
 this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(
list=>{
  let array = list.map(item=>{
    let maintainerName=this.maintainerService.getMaintainerName(item.payload.val()['maintainer']);
    let clientName=this.getclientsService.getClientName(item.payload.val()['client']);
    return{
      $key: item.key,
      maintainerName,
      clientName,
      ...item.payload.val()
    };
  });
  this.listData= new MatTableDataSource(array);
  this.listData.sort=this.sort;
  this.listData.paginator=this.paginator;
  this.listData.filterPredicate=(data, filter)=>{
    return this.displayColumns.some(ele=>{
      return ele != 'actions' && data[ele].toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1;
    });
  }
}
```

I'm tryinig to get maintainers list from firebase in the same way and it works!

Comment: Okay. That means there is no object that matches the predicate you passed to `find`. Step through the code and find out if there are any elements in `this.array` that have a `$key` property equal to the `$key` value you're passing in, at the time you are calling `getClientName`.

Comment: These are properties from database: form: FormGroup=new FormGroup({
    $key: new FormControl(null),
    clientID: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    address: new FormControl(''),
    city: new FormControl(''),
    phone: new FormControl(''),
    email: new FormControl(''),
    contPers: new FormControl('')
  });